# long long int in C, Mac OS X, Xcode 3.2.5, field width

Tags: c, xcode, macos, 64-bit

In this sample:

```
long long int x = 1<<38;
NSLog(@"Hello, World!, %qi", x);
```

I got "warning: left shift count >= width of type", and the value zero for x.

The length of a long long int is 8, so we should be able to shift up 63.

I'se puzzled....And would sho' 'preciate some help.

Answer (score 14):

It's not `x` that's the problem, it's the `1`, which is a signed **integer** literal constant.

Try this instead:

```
long long int x = 1LL << 38;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat!  I'm puzzled though that the normal conversion doesn't take place.  Still, no philosophising, encapsulate & move on...:-)

Comment: @John, the normal conversion takes place *after* the evaluation of the right hand side, something like `long long int x = ((long long int)(1 << 38))`. There is no such thing in C that would inspect an expression and evaluate it according to the expected type corresponding to the usage that you have with that expression.